combining 50th percentiles curve gamlss in one plot
I am a seasoned R programmer trying to help my friend to visualize percentile growth curves using gamlss. I have been successfully produce the curve for each group. Now the problem is she asked me to combine the 50th percentile of the two group in one plot. How can I achieve that?
Here is my code for 50 percentile of each group:
boys height:
centiles(mboys, dataa$Age, cent=50, ylab="Berat Badan (kg)", xlab="Usia (tahun)", lwd.centiles = 2.5, col.centiles = "red", main = "Anak Laki-laki", lty.centiles = 1)

girls height:
centiles(girlsmodel, girlsbhh$Age, cent = 50, ylab = "Berat Badan (kg)", xlab = "Usia (tahun)", lwd.centiles = 2.5, col.centiles = "black", main = "Anak Perempuan", lty.centiles = 1)

I want to achieve this:
enter image description here
I have tried to read the documentation but still not know how to do it. And I have tried to use chatGPT but failed.

Try with centiles.pred function to extract the percentiles of each model.
centiles.pred(mboys,xname="Age",xvalues=seq(0,19,by=1))
The xvalues argument is the new values for the explanatory variable where the prediction will take place (I assume the age of a boy in years from 0 to 19). The results is a data.frame, that you can joint with girlsmodel and plot.
